# Is necessary to bind params after each prepare in PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have the following question about PDO:

If I will execute multiple queries I need to use bindParam method each time I call prepare?

Example:

```
$connection->prepare( "SELECT * FROM table WHERE y = :y" );
$connection->bindParam( ":y", $y );

$connection->prepare( "SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE y = :w" );
$connection->bindParam( ":w", $w );
```

OR can I do better using something like:

```
$connection->bindParam( ":y", $y );
$connection->bindParam( ":w", $w );

$connection->prepare( "SELECT * FROM table WHERE y = :y" );
$connection->prepare( "SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE y = :w" );
```

OR:

```
$connection->prepare( "SELECT * FROM table WHERE y = :y" );
$connection->prepare( "SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE y = :w" );

$connection->bindParam( ":y", $y );
$connection->bindParam( ":w", $w );
```

Which order and what is possible?

Comment: you wouldn't execute multple query at single execute . you need each query ,bind param and execute separately for each query

Comment: None of those will work.  The return from `prepare` is a prepared statement. The `bindParam` is a method associated with the *statement*, not the *connection*.  The value of the variable bound to the placeholder is evaluated when the statement `execute` method is called. I suggest you review the PDO documentation for examples.

Comment: If you need to execute multiple queries with the same parameter, it means that most likely your database design is wrong. Make just a single table for all your similar data, and thus you will need just a single query to run.

Comment: If binding each param is to much work you can pass an array with parameters into the `execute` method of the `stmt`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you [bind params](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) you bind them to a prepared statement not to a connection, so this actually wouldn't work

```
$connection->bindParam( ":w", $w );
```

Instead, you would need to do:

```
$stmt = $connection->prepare( "SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE y = :w" );
$stmt->bindParam( ":w", $w );
```

Which automatically implies that you need to bind parameters separately for each statement.